# How can I add node packages to the aws serverless typescript template?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, aws-serverless

I've been experimenting with serverless lately, and I would like to add some node packages to my project. I'm currently using the aws-nodejs-typescript template.

I add packages using npm install, and then import them into my handler functions. They seem to be working ok at that point, vs code is able to pick up on the typings. When I come to deploy the project however webpack appears unable to resolve them. Im tearing my hair out wondering why it's having such trouble when as far as I can tell this is the normal way add packages in node.

The added packages appear in the package.json file as normal dependencies just like the ones from the template, but the ones from the template work and the added ones don't.

How do you add npm packages to serverless projects?

Comment: It is worth mentioning that you are using the  Serverless Framework

Comment: FYI AWS SAM CLI now has built-in support for nodejs-typescript, and it uses esbuild (instead of webpack) under the hood for transpiling the ts code.